# how to build qt3d with Dynamic OpenGL implementation (qt5.4 -opengl dynamic)

Tags: opengl, dynamic, qt3d, qt5.4

I have qt5.4 compiled with -opengl dynamic. I have tested it and the fallback works fine. Now I would like to also compile qt3d with the dynamic opengl qt libraries. Is that possible? Problem is that my building ends with linking problem below. And if I understand it correctly I should not add any opengl libraries....how can I solve this?

```
\ConvertUTF" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\zlib" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\irrXML" -I"..\..\3rdparty\assimp\contrib\unzip" -I"scene_bezier" -I"network" -I"graphicsview" -I"textures" -I"surfaces" -I"api" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore\5.4.0" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore\5.4.0\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui\5.4.0" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui\5.4.0\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtOpenGL" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtANGLE" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtCore" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\include\QtNetwork" -I".moc\debug" -I"C:\Qt\5.4_angle\5.4\msvc2013\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Fo.obj\debug\ @C:\Users\eDS\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_qgltexture2d_p.obj.1576.138606.jom
moc_qgltexture2d_p.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /VERSION:5.30 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\lib\Qt53Dd.dll @C:\Users\eDS\AppData\Local\Temp\Qt53Dd.dll.1576.142070.jom
   Creating library ..\..\lib\Qt53Dd.lib and object ..\..\lib\Qt53Dd.exp
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor4f@16 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QGLPainter::updateFixedFunction(class QFlags<enum QGLPainter::Update>)" (?updateFixedFunction@QGLPainter@@QAEXV?$QFlags@W4Update@QGLPainter@@@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColorPointer@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl qt_gl_setVertexAttribute(enum QGL::VertexAttribute,class QGLAttributeValue const &)" (?qt_gl_setVertexAttribute@@YAXW4VertexAttribute@QGL@@ABVQGLAttributeValue@@@Z)
qglpainter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLightModelfv@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QGLPainter::updateFixedFunction(class QFlags<enum QGLPainter::Update>)" (?updateFixedFunction@QGLPainter@@QAEXV?
```

Comment: as @AndonMColreman said, those functions are old and are not in OpenGL ES 2.0 which is notably the main set of functions that ANGLE (which is the alternative OpenGL implementation that QT can use) implements. So, I would expect those functions to only be available with `-opengl desktop`

Answer (score 0):

`glColor4f`, `glColorPointer` and `glLightModelfv` are all OpenGL 1.1 or older functions.

On Windows, it is the responsibility of `OpenGL32.lib` to provide those at ***link-time***. Any parts of OpenGL newer than 1.1 on Windows have to be loaded dynamically at *run-time* and Qt actually does this for you if you use the appropriate wrapper classes.

In any event, to solve this simply add `OpenGL32.lib` to your linker dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The article that mentions this new Qt feature (`-opengl dynamic` I mean)
says:

> Applications that want to be dynamically switchable must always use
>   QOpenGLFunctions and be prepared to function both on OpenGL and OpenGL
>   ES 2.0

[source](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/11/27/qt-weekly-21-dynamic-opengl-implementation-loading-in-qt-5-4/)

So, you can not use functions like `glColor4f`, `glColorPointer`, `glLightModelfv`, `glBegin`, etc. that have been removed from OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: I see, so that means that qt3d is not ready for the new dynamic opengl implementation,...right?